# How to enable and create multiple workspaces in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity

Is there any way to create and access multiple workspaces in Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to enable workspaces in Ubuntu 15.04. To do this:

1. Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System Settings.
2. In the Personal section, click Appearance and select the Behavior tab.
3. Tick the Enable workspaces check box.

Now you can open the Launcher and click the workspace switcher icon near the bottom. By default, Ubuntu shows 4 workspaces, arranged in 2 rows and 2 columns.

If you want to add more workspaces, you can install and use Unity Tweek Tool to add additional workspaces.